# Not able to access RDS Postgres from PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS `Postgres` instance created which is marked `Publicly accessible` and has inbound rule to grant access from anywhere for type `Postgres` (imaged attached). I am not able to access the `db` from `PgAdmin`. Interestingly, I was able to access it until few days back however when I tried logging in yesterday/today, the connection is getting timed out.

Note: An AWS `lambda` function is able to insert records into the same `db`.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error message?  Carefully review the pgAdmin settings.  Try it from `psql` instead.